# Google maps in accordion slideshow, how to add marker?

Tags: javascript

I have google map in accordion slideshow but i don't know how to add marker on the map. Can someone help me? here is the code

```
var gmap;
        function initializeGmap() {
            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 15,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.023100,14.742014), // google map location to show
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'),
                myOptions);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways of doing this:
1- Saving a custom map and embedding it in your page ( no big programming knowledge riquired) -> [Google custom maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/62843?hl=en)
2- Using the googla maps API v3 -<[Google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a Marker object
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                position: position
            });